# jqGrid is not rendered after data is retrieved from server

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am having trouble to display data in jqGrid after data is retrieved from the server.
jqGrid shows Loading message however does not show the data after its done loading.

```
    $("#list27").jqGrid({
        url: '/server/getdata.do?name=afonso',
        datatype: "json",
        height: 355,
        width: 750,
        colNames:['Email','Name', 'Empno', 'Notes'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'email', width:200},
            {name:'name', width:200},
            {name:'empno', width:100},
            {name:'notes', width:250}
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",

    caption: "Loading data from server at once" 
});
```

Comment: could you include in the text of your question the exact JSON data received from the server. You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to catch the data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for javascript errors (#1
   culprit)
2. Check `url:
   '/server/getdata.do?name=afonso',`
   to make sure that it is actually
   returning proper data.

Comment: yes it does return json data. the problem is jqGrid wont render it. if I store result in local variable and then reference it in jqGrid it works.